# Download for Holo Dark nav drawer icon

Tags: android

I went to the [navigation drawer tutorial site](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) where it gave me a [link](http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Navigation_Drawer_Icon_20130516.zip) to download the holo icons for the action bar.

There were two directories, one for Holo Light and one for Holo Dark. Both icons, however, looked exactly the same to me. It appears as both are the Holo Light icon.

How can I get the Holo Dark icon?

Answer (score 1):

Look here:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

It should be also in other places soon.

Comment: This is the site I linked in my post that only offered Holo Light icons from what I could find. Is there a more specific link on the page that will work correctly?

Comment: There are Holo Light and Holo Dark icons in this package.

Comment: Both icons seem to be too dark to be Holo Dark (which is almost white to match the other Holo Dark icons, as far as I expected). I might have to just make my own icon.

Comment: But it's not an usual icon... so I think you should use these from Google instead of creating your own.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the icon downloads that you are referring to (as linked in the other answer, and tagged with the date 20130516) it appears to me that they are similar but not the same.

I'm not saying they are well suited to their themes (and I certainly wouldn't put it past Google to make the sort of mistake that you suspect) but in fact I believe they are correct.